# Automated DataSource Creation on WSO2 Server

Tags: wso2-esb

Is there any way of automate the creation of the Datasources on WSO2 Servers?

I saw there is a datasources.properties file that we can use, but I did not find a documentation for it.

Also, saw there is a NDataSource admin service.

Which is the prefered way of automate the data source creation on WSO2 Servers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [1]  on how you can change the default databases and which configuration files you need to update.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Working+with+Databases

Comment: Thanks, I have used for that a groovy script that invokes the NDataSource admin service to create the Datasource on WSO2.